# Compress spaces in cksum output

Tags: solaris, checksum

My issue:
How long is the length of the output of " cksum " command ?

When I run the " cksum " I command returns the following:

```
cksum file.txt

2699968955      155920  file.txt
```

There are a lot of blank space between the information. Why? 
Can I get that there is only a blank ?

```
2699968955 155920 file.txt
```

My unix shell `/usr/bin/ksh`

The file:

```
file.txt
```

My system: `SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-23 sun4v sparc sun4v`

Comment: just for the record, if you want something stronger than the ancient `cksum` command there is also the `digest` command. With that you can easily generate stronger hashes like md5 and sha-X.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt very much that cksum would bother providing any significant formatting options, but

```
cksum file.txt | awk '{ print $1,$2,$3 }'
```

will do what you want.

Comment: Breaks with filenames containing whitespace, but the idea seems sound

Answer (score 0):

```
cksum file.txt | sed -e 's/  */ /' -e 's/  */ /2'
```

This would compress the first and second set of consecutive spaces only, leaving any blanks in the actual filename untouched.

It does this by using `sed` to replace the first set of one or more spaces with a single space, and then applies the exact same substitution again, but now skipping the first match (this is what the `2` at the end of the `s` command in `sed` does).

Comment: That will break filenames with spaces and is really no better than `echo $(cksum file.txt)` or `echo $(cksum <"$file") "$file"`.

Comment: @mosvy I rewrote it from scratch. Better now. Thanks for the heads up.